# Convolutional neural network, how the second conv layer works on the first pooling layer

Tags: tensorflow

I'm reading material from the TensorFlow website:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

Suppose we have 10 greyscale monochrome 28x28 pixel images,

1. If we apply 32 5x5 convolutional filters with 0 padding in the 1st conv layer, we get 10*32*28*28 data.
2. If We apply 2x2 max pooling with stride 2 in the 1st pooling, we get 10*32*14*14 data.
3. By now, one image has become a 14*14 size image with 32 channels.

So, if we apply a second convolutional layer(let's say 64 5x5 filters as in the link), do we apply these filters to each channel of each image and get 10*32*64*14*14 data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No. You do apply the filters to each channel and each image, but you don't get `10*32*64*14*14` output dimensions. The dimensionality of the output is going to be `10*64*14*14`, because the layer specified 64 output channels per image. In turn, the weights used for this convolution will have size `32*64*5*5` (64 5-by-5 filters for every channel on the input).

Comment: Ignoring batch size, does the filter of the 2nd conv takes different values for the 32 channels from the 1st round conv&pooling? If they are the same, the weights should have size `64*5*5`, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "1st round"? Your `5*5` filters take into account all 32 channels on the input to produce one resulting feature map. This process is done 64 times with 64 different weights each time, otherwise you would end up with 64 times the same feature map.

Answer (score 2):

No.
If you convolve & pad (ignoring the batch size) a `14x14x32` volume with a set of 64 `5x5` filters, you'll end up with a `14x14x64` output volume

Every single convolutional filter is convolved along the whole input depth. Thus, your `14x14x32` input volume is convolved with a `5x5` filter and then the output is a `14x14x1` feature map.

Then, the second `5x5` filter of the stack of 64 filters, is convolved again with the input volume.
The same operation is done for each one of the 64 filters and the resulting feature maps are stacked, forming your output volume `14x14x64`

Comment: When convolving along the whole input depth, do we add the values up along the depth with 64 weights to get one element in the `14x14x1` matrix?